# The word "disposition" in the words "gender disposition"

Tags: word-meaning

Currently reading this article, there is a line,

> “Biden is trying to reclaim the vision of America that was there during the Obama administration, a vision that was much more diverse, much more religiously tolerant, much more tolerant of different kinds of gender **dispositions** and gender presentations,” said Norma Mendoza-Denton, a professor of anthropology at UCLA

Which of the following definitions should be applied to here in this case?

> 1a: prevailing tendency, mood, or inclination

> b: temperamental makeup

> c: the tendency of something to act in a certain manner under given circumstances

> 2: the act or the power of disposing or the state of being disposed: such as

> a: administration, control

> b: final arrangement : settlement

> the disposition of the case

> c(1) : transfer to the care or possession of another

> (2) : the power of such transferal

> d: orderly arrangement

May be 1a or 1c or 2b?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is almost certainly not 2b, which is almost exclusively used in legal proceedings, like the example you included. Here, "the disposition of the case" refers to a stage in the process of a legal case in court.

Most likely, Professor Mendoza-Denton is using "disposition" in the sense of 1a here, in order to point out the multi-faceted nature of one's gender *identity* by delineating inclination from presentation. That is, one can "feel like a male" (disposition) without overtly acting or dressing like one (presentation). This is a "disposition" in the sense of 1a.

Comment: Yes, inclination.

Comment: Of the definitions provided, 1a is likely the best.  But social scientists like Mendoza-Denton use specialized language (which is often not easy to distinguish from everyday language) and these definitions are rarely found in general-purpose dictionaries.  The concept of gender disposition might be sufficiently explained by definition 1a, but for the sake of completeness, here are some references ["A dispositional account of gender"](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/215159564.pdf), ["Behavioral Disposition"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/social-sciences/behavioral-disposition)